# Getting 404 not found error when running spring jpa project on tomcat7

Tags: spring, ubuntu, tomcat7

I am trying to deploy a spring jpa project on tomcat7 on ubuntu13.04. I started tomcat using `sh startup.sh`
and I got the message "Tomcat Started". 
Before this I copied my ROOT.war to /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps and have given full permission to this folder also. And I can see it is correctly structured.

And below is my web.xml

```
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Test App</display-name> 
 <servlet>
     <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name> 
     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class> 
 <init-param>
     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> 
     <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value> 
     </init-param>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
 </servlet>
 <context-param>
     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> 
     <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/spring-context.xml</param-value> 
 </context-param>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name> 
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> 
 </servlet-mapping>
 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener class> 
 </listener>
 </web-app>
```

And below code is part of my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/issue")
public class IssueController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     function to handle above request
}
```

Below is my mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.hello" />
<mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager"   />
       <bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
                    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true" />
                    <property name="favorParameter" value="true" />
                    <property name="mediaTypes" >
                        <value>
                            json=application/json
                            xml=application/xml
                        </value>
                    </property>
      </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

But now when I am running `http://localhost:8080/issue/1`, I am getting 404 page not found.

Comment: Do you have a ContextLoaderListener in your web.xml?

Comment: can you share your web.xml complete?

Comment: As a test please try applying this little change (value="/user/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET). Let me know how it behaves (i think i know the problem). Also make sure you call /issue/user/1 to access the method.

Comment: @Aeseir: I will test it and let you know the results. Can't do it now. But can you give me some hint. I am eager to know the issue.

Comment: @Skizzo: Posted complete web.xml

Comment: @King Think the url you are colling is wrong. Try `http://localhost:8080/ROOT/issue/1`

Comment: @Jens: but why ROOT? I have mentioned url-mapping as"/" only. As per my understanding it should process all urls with http://localhost:8080/ depending on the controller mapping. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @King In my understanding `/` means all urls in this context where `ROOT` is the context

Comment: Your web.xml and the URL you are accessing seem correct. ROOT is the [default application for tomcat](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_make_my_web_application_be_the_Tomcat_default_application.3F). Can you share your mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml and spring-context.xml?

Comment: @Aeseir: I tested it but it is still giving me resource not avalable same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your web.xml in this way:

```
    <web-app>
     <servlet>
         <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name> 
         <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class> 
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> 
                <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value> 
            </init-param>
         <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
     </servlet>


     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name> 
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
     </servlet-mapping>
     <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener class> 
     </listener>
    </web-app>
```